# AWS Quicksight calculated filed error - division operator not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset with the following fields in Quicksight:

`ordered_units`, `product_category`

I am trying to add a calculated field that will give me the percentage of items ordered for each item category. i.e. `ordered_units / sum(ordered_units) group by product category`

The formula I am using for the calculated field is:

```
({ordered_units}/sumOver(sum({ordered_units}),[{product_category}])) * 100
```

But it is not letting me save the field and gives the error:

> We encountered an error trying to save your calculated field. Please
> try creating it again.

Is there something I am missing or not doing correctly?